# How to display photo library in collectionView using less memory

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

I'm facing the problem that people are saying that the application crashes when loading photos library in collectionView. Most of the time they have more than 2-3 thousands of photos. For me it's working fine. (I have less than 1000 photos in my library).

**Question: maybe there's any way to display images in collectionView more "smart" and using less memory?**

P.S Maybe when user have all of his photos in iCloud that can cause crash too? Because until now I thought that application is not downloading photos when loading it into the cell. Maybe someone can prove or disapprove that fact.

Here's my function:

```
func grabPhotos(){

    let imgManager = PHImageManager.default()

    let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
    requestOptions.isSynchronous = false
    requestOptions.deliveryMode = .opportunistic // Quality of images
    requestOptions.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true

    requestOptions.isSynchronous = true
    requestOptions.progressHandler = {  (progress, error, stop, info) in
        print("progress: \(progress)")
    }

    let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]

    if let fetchResult : PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions) {

        if fetchResult.count > 0 {
            for i in 0..<fetchResult.count {
                imgManager.requestImage(for: fetchResult.object(at: i) , targetSize: CGSize(width: 150, height: 150), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: { image, error in
                    self.imageArray.append(image!)
                    self.kolekcija.reloadData()
                })
            }
        }
        else {
            print("You got no photos")
            kolekcija.reloadData()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This certainly isn't an answer, but I believe a `UICollectionView` works exactly the same way as a `UITableView` - that is, you *are not* working with thousands of cells. These controls are built to use as little memory as possible by queueing their cells. I wonder if your issue lies elsewhere. Maybe how you are retiring/storing your datasource?

Comment: Though irrelevant to the problem, but stop reloading the collection view every time a new item added in `self.imageArray`. Simply reload the collection view while your loop complete. It wont do any thing with realtime image showing because the main queue is busy in preparing your image array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
self.imageArray.append(image!)
```

Never make an array of images. Images are huge, and you'll run out of memory.

This is a collection view. You simply supply the image on demand in `itemForRowAt:`, and what you supply is a *small* version of the image (a so-called *thumbnail*), the smallest possible for the display size. Thus there are, at any time, only enough thumbnails to fill the visible screen; that doesn't take very much memory, plus the runtime can release the image memory when an image is scrolled off the screen.

That is what PHCachingImageManager is for. Look closely at how Apple handles this in their sample code:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/UsingPhotosFramework/Listings/Shared_AssetGridViewController_swift.html

There is no array of images *anywhere* in that example.

Comment: It's a great solution. Dropped from 80 mb to 10 mb when there's around 1000 photos:) Anyway, I don't know maybe it's my fault or maybe not but with this code the quality of picked image is not that great. (there's no big difference but still). Anyway, thank you!

Comment: @matt awesome reference buddy. albeit when I scroll down the collectionView grid of images at high speed or when I scroll a significant amount of images (say like 700), at some point the app terminates due to memory issue. any thoughts on that? T.I.A

Comment: @HudiIlfeld Sounds like you are retaining the images as you receive them. Don't do that. As I said in my answer, the only images you should be hanging on to are the thumbnail (small) images actually shown in the collection view at any given moment. Apple has excellent WWDC videos on how to make sure you aren't caching images you don't need to cache.

Answer (score 0):

Working in Swift 5. Get the photo assets, but don't load the photos until cellForItem iteration. Happy coding.

```
    var personalImages: PHFetchResult<AnyObject>!
            
    func getPersonalPhotos() {
         let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
         fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
         self.personalImages = (PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions) as AnyObject?) as! PHFetchResult<AnyObject>? 
            
         photoLibraryCollectionView.reloadData()
    }
        
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
         return personalImages.count
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "insertCellIdentifierHere", for: indexPath) as! InsertACollectionViewCellHere
    
    let asset: PHAsset = self.personalImages[indexPath.item] as! PHAsset
    let itemWidth = photoLibraryCollectionView.frame.size.width / 2
    let itemSize = CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemWidth / 2) // adjust to your preferences
    
    PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: itemSize, contentMode: .aspectFill, options: nil, resultHandler: {(result, info)in
        if result != nil {
            
            cell.photoImageView.image = result
        }
    })
    
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
    cell.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
    return cell
}
```